# Anime or manga where the main character moves to a city and sells talismans

Tags: story-identification, manga, anime

The main character was transferred to or reincarnated to another world. When he gets there he sells his small house to go to the city.

He starts selling talismans but nobody buys them, but when 2 people are fighting he sells talismans to both of them, back and forth, to counter each other's talismans. Eventually he opens a banks with lower rates which becomes big.

Comment: Are all of the talismans cursed?

Comment: And do you remember whether it was a manga, an anime, or both?