# Manga where the protagonist can only make cursed items (and tokens that remove curses) and gets kicked out of his party

Tags: story-identification, manga

I ran into this while researching [Anime or manga where the main character moves to a city and sells talismans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268888/anime-or-manga-where-the-main-character-moves-to-a-city-and-sells-talismans), but I can't seem to find it again. The protagonist gets kicked out of his adventuring party because they feel he's a burden to them on account of that he can only craft cursed items. I want to say that he had a job title like "cursificer". Anyhow, after he's kicked out, he sets up a stall in town selling the cursed items with the idea that they look "neat" or "edgy", but he only starts making sales when he bundles tokens with them to remove curses. As it turns out, that's a very rare ability. All of the cursed items have a negative effect, but they also offer beneficial effects that can far out-strip the curse.

Meanwhile, his old group hires a new mage to replace him, and they set out to kill an ogre, only to find that they're no longer "S-Class" because they've been fighting with the benefit of his cursed items all of this time (I have a vague memory that part of why it was working was that he constantly operated under the weight of all of the curses with his team getting the benefits and him getting the drawbacks). They're convinced that he cursed them for being kicked out, but the new mage starts to realize the truth of the matter and tracks down the protagonist. I think the last chapter I read had a noble of some sort contacting the protagonist so as to gain access to his items and/or his Remove Curse tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the process of figuring out the proper spelling for his job title, I found the work in question, *[S-Rank Party kara Kaiko sareta "Jugushi": "Noroi no Item" shika Tsukuremasen ga, Sono Seinou wa Artifact-kyuu nari......!](https://myanimelist.net/manga/146793/S-Rank_Party_kara_Kaiko_sareta_Jugushi__Noroi_no_Item_shika_Tsukuremasen_ga_Sono_Seinou_wa_Artifact-kyuu_nari)*, aka *My S-Rank Party Fired Me for Being a Cursificer ~ I Can Only Make “Cursed Items”, but They’re Artifact Class!*, by LAgun, Ogawa, and Nishiki:

> Gaile, a Cursificer, is left penniless when he's expelled from his party as soon as they reach S-Rank. Apparently he wasn't contributing enough?! But they hadn't realized that his cursed items outperform even holy relics and legendary equipment! Gaile decides to try to make a living on his own off of his cursed items.

It's apparently based off of a web novel on *[Shōsetsuka ni Narō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dsetsuka_ni_Nar%C5%8D)*.